# When indexed view updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, indexed-view

I create a indexed view `View1` on `Table1` and `Table2` and have instead of trigger and after trigger on `Table1` that use of `View1`. It seem that data of `View1` not change when I use this view on instead of trigger and after trigger. But I want to use `View1` with new data when use this view on after trigger. How can I do it. It should be noted that I use `with Noexpand` hint when use indexed view (when don't use `with noexpand` hint in `SQL Server 2008 R2` act this indexed view such as no indexed view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexed view is updated after all triggers on the base tables are executed. You can see that in the query plan. There will be **only one** clustered index update on the view.

However, you can create `INSTEAD OF` triggers on the view and then make all your operations on the indexed view. However,there are some restrictions when updating/inserting/deleting through an updateable view. You can read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Note that views allow only `INSTEAD OF` triggers, not `AFTER` too.

The most important thing to know about updating indexed views is that any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table.

Comment: Some of the requirements repeat requirements for creation of indexed views, and indexed views are those the OP is dealing with. Perhaps it would be slightly more helpful if you omitted the duplicate requirements.